# Matrix Field Count Records

Tags: matrix, plugin-supertable

Is there an easy way to return the total number of entries in a Super Table within a Matrix field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean how many rows the table has?

```
{{ matrixblock.superTableFieldHandle|length }}
```

Or the number of blocks of a matrix field?

```
{{ parent.matrixFieldHandle|length }}
```

To get the number of blocks for each row

```
{% for row in entry.superTableMatrix %}
    {{ row.matrix|length %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get all the records listed in the SuperTable across each Matrix entry within the Entry.  I am not sure if I am saying that correct.  Basically I have 4 matrix records and within one of the matrix blocks there is a SuperTable and there would be 5-100 records in thost SuperTables.  So combined could be 20-400 lines since the SuperTable is a text field.

Comment: Basically need the total count for all those SuperTable entries for each Entry.

Comment: You can loop through each field and add the number for each element